# Nginx How to prevent processing requests with undefined server names

Tags: nginx

Nginx is 1.14.1 version
have several virtual hosts and default in the /etc/nging/sites-enabled:
I've tried to configure using this doc: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html
default

```
server {
       listen      80;
        server_name "";
        return      444;

}
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
            server_name _;
            ssl_certificate ....
        ssl_certificate_key .....

            add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000';
        return 444;
}
```

domain1

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1;
    return 301 https://$server_name;
}

server {
       server_name domain1;
       listen 443 ssl; 
..................

}
```

but when tried to get access using server IP nginx redirect to domain1. please help what's wrong here. I'd like to deny access by IP to sites and leave only requests with domain name

Comment: You haven't marked the first `server` block with `default_server`.

Comment: I've tried to make config line: listen      80 default_server; but result is the same

Comment: was cache problem. Chrome cached redirect. Thank you!